# Using the SQL connector for an Azure Logic App I want to get the inserted row ID

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app which inserts a row to a SQL table through the insert row action of the SQL connector.

Is there a way to get the auto-increment row id of the inserted row as an output or do I need to create a complete separate action for that? I need the ID to insert more rows into different tables that contain a foreign key to the main table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created an auto-incremented Id on your table, you don't have anything to do:

- Create the `Sql server  - Insert Row` action
  [image: Azure Logic App - SQL Server - Insert Row Action]
- In your next step, the Id will be available
  [image]

You can check on the run history that the Id has been returned:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I need the ID to insert more rows into different tables that contain a foreign key to the main table.

Well, then my advice is...don't.  Use a Stored Procedure instead.

The reason is that LogicApps + SQL Connector is much less transactional that other platforms.  The risk is getting half way through your inserts and a problems happens.  That means lots of messy cleanup.

The Stored Procedure can be used as an atomic transaction without any special consideration or other 'things' like MSDTC.

Comment: Yep good point, I always try to encapsulate SQL into Stored procedure. Have you ever encounter problem with it ? Is the logic app returned the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ???

Comment: I wouldn't think so specifically.  *You* can return any value you want, including scope_identity, identity, rowcount or whatever value you can read or conjure.